# Table is responsive on Outlook but is not in Gmail

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

I had a three tables that I want to be responsive when view the email on mobile or tablet. On desktop they showed like 3 columns and I want on mobile they show as one column.

The problem is on Gmail it is showing like 3 columns and Outlook it is show like one column.

I don't know if is an bug on code or if Gmail don't recognize some style.

```css
 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
           table[class=devicewidthinner-full] {background-color: #ccc !important; width: 100%!important;text-align:center!important;}
           img[class=banner] {width: 280px!important;height:140px!important;}
           img[class=colimg2] {width: 280px!important;height:140px!important;}
           td[class=mobile-hide]{display:none!important;}
           td[class="padding-bottom25"]{padding-bottom:25px!important;}
 }
```

```html
<table width="186" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full" style="background-color: #ccc;">
 <tbody>
    <!-- image 2 -->
    <tr>
       <td width="100%" align="center" class="devicewidth"><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="" border="0" width="186" height="130" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;"></a>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end of image2 -->
    <tr>
       <td>
          <!-- start of text content table -->  
          <table width="186" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full">
             <tbody>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- title2 -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #666666; text-align:center; line-height: 24px;" st-title="3col-title1">
                      Lorem Ipsum
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- end of title2 -->
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="10" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- content2 -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #889098; text-align:center; line-height: 24px;" st-content="3col-content1">
                      Lorem Ipsum 
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- end of content2 -->
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- read more -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #0a8cd8;  text-align:center; line-height: 20px;" st-title="3col-readmore1" class="padding-bottom25">
                      <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #FF5500;">Here</a>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
                <!-- end of read more -->
             </tbody>
          </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end of text content table -->
 </tbody>
</table>

<table width="20" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<table width="186" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full" style="background-color: #ccc;">
 <tbody>
    <!-- image 2 -->
    <tr>
       <td width="100%" align="center" class="devicewidth"><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="" border="0" width="186" height="130" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;"></a>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end of image2 -->
    <tr>
       <td>
          <!-- start of text content table -->  
          <table width="186" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full">
             <tbody>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- title2 -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #666666; text-align:center; line-height: 24px;" st-title="3col-title1">
                      Lorem Ipsum
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- end of title2 -->
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="10" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- content2 -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #889098; text-align:center; line-height: 24px;" st-content="3col-content1">
                      Lorem Ipsum 
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- end of content2 -->
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- read more -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #0a8cd8;  text-align:center; line-height: 20px;" st-title="3col-readmore1" class="padding-bottom25">
                      <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #FF5500;">Here</a>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
                <!-- end of read more -->
             </tbody>
          </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end of text content table -->
 </tbody>
</table>

<table width="20" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<table width="186" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full" style="background-color: #ccc;">
 <tbody>
    <!-- image 2 -->
    <tr>
       <td width="100%" align="center" class="devicewidth"><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="" border="0" width="186" height="130" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;"></a>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end of image2 -->
    <tr>
       <td>
          <!-- start of text content table -->  
          <table width="186" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full">
             <tbody>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- title2 -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #666666; text-align:center; line-height: 24px;" st-title="3col-title1">
                      Lorem Ipsum
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- end of title2 -->
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="10" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- content2 -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #889098; text-align:center; line-height: 24px;" st-content="3col-content1">
                      Lorem Ipsum 
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- end of content2 -->
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- read more -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #0a8cd8;  text-align:center; line-height: 20px;" st-title="3col-readmore1" class="padding-bottom25">
                      <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #FF5500;">Here</a>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
                <!-- end of read more -->
             </tbody>
          </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end of text content table -->
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gmail is a little tricky to code for, there is a company called MailChimp that have an online article (https://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/limitations-of-html-email) which should help you get the coding right for gmail.

Comment: @Dan yes it is tricky but easy if you know what you are looking for. MailChimp is good but it doesnt give you the flexibility with pre built templates we coders are usually after. My answer below shows how you can use media queries in Gmail to make you email responsive ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the media query. Gmail has stopped supporting class selectors sometime ago. If you change your media query as below it will work. I have tested the below code in Gmail app (v8.1.7) but it should work with any release after November last year.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
           .devicewidthinner-full {background-color: #ccc !important; width: 100%!important;text-align:center!important;}
           .banner {width: 280px!important;height:140px!important;}
          .colimg2 {width: 280px!important;height:140px!important;}
           .mobile-hide{display:none!important;}
           .padding-bottom25{padding-bottom:25px!important;}
 }
```

```html
<table width="186" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full" style="background-color: #ccc;">
 <tbody>
    <!-- image 2 -->
    <tr>
       <td width="100%" align="center" class="devicewidth"><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="" border="0" width="186" height="130" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;"></a>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end of image2 -->
    <tr>
       <td>
          <!-- start of text content table -->  
          <table width="186" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full">
             <tbody>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- title2 -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #666666; text-align:center; line-height: 24px;" st-title="3col-title1">
                      Lorem Ipsum
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- end of title2 -->
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="10" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- content2 -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #889098; text-align:center; line-height: 24px;" st-content="3col-content1">
                      Lorem Ipsum 
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- end of content2 -->
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- read more -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #0a8cd8;  text-align:center; line-height: 20px;" st-title="3col-readmore1" class="padding-bottom25">
                      <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #FF5500;">Here</a>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
                <!-- end of read more -->
             </tbody>
          </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end of text content table -->
 </tbody>
</table>

<table width="20" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<table width="186" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full" style="background-color: #ccc;">
 <tbody>
    <!-- image 2 -->
    <tr>
       <td width="100%" align="center" class="devicewidth"><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="" border="0" width="186" height="130" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;"></a>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end of image2 -->
    <tr>
       <td>
          <!-- start of text content table -->  
          <table width="186" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full">
             <tbody>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- title2 -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #666666; text-align:center; line-height: 24px;" st-title="3col-title1">
                      Lorem Ipsum
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- end of title2 -->
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="10" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- content2 -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #889098; text-align:center; line-height: 24px;" st-content="3col-content1">
                      Lorem Ipsum 
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- end of content2 -->
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- read more -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #0a8cd8;  text-align:center; line-height: 20px;" st-title="3col-readmore1" class="padding-bottom25">
                      <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #FF5500;">Here</a>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
                <!-- end of read more -->
             </tbody>
          </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end of text content table -->
 </tbody>
</table>

<table width="20" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<table width="186" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full" style="background-color: #ccc;">
 <tbody>
    <!-- image 2 -->
    <tr>
       <td width="100%" align="center" class="devicewidth"><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="" border="0" width="186" height="130" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;"></a>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end of image2 -->
    <tr>
       <td>
          <!-- start of text content table -->  
          <table width="186" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidthinner-full">
             <tbody>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- title2 -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #666666; text-align:center; line-height: 24px;" st-title="3col-title1">
                      Lorem Ipsum
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- end of title2 -->
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="10" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- content2 -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #889098; text-align:center; line-height: 24px;" st-content="3col-content1">
                      Lorem Ipsum 
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- end of content2 -->
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacing -->
                <!-- read more -->
                <tr>
                   <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #0a8cd8;  text-align:center; line-height: 20px;" st-title="3col-readmore1" class="padding-bottom25">
                      <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #FF5500;">Here</a>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td width="100%" height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
                <!-- end of read more -->
             </tbody>
          </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end of text content table -->
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Let me know if you have issues.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately your code doens't work, gmail keeps displaying 2 columns and the last collum below instead 1 collum width 100%

Comment: I had tested the code in Gmail app and gave the version number above? Which device are you using it on? I tested the above code on pixel 2 XL